# How can I verify that these two calculations for a derivative are equal?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am working through Calculus with Analytic Geometry by Simmons. Section 3.6 (Derivatives of Higher Order) page 107 question #25 has me calculating the derivative of the following function..

$$
(\frac{x^3+8}{x^2})^{3/4}
$$

The answer in the back of the book is
$$
\frac{3(x^3 - 16)}{4x^3} \sqrt[4]{\frac{x^2}{x^3 + 8}}
$$

The answer I get when I use the deriv feature on wolfram alpha is
$$
\frac{3(x^3-16)}{4x^3\sqrt[4]{\frac{8}{x^2} + x}}
$$

And when I calculate it myself (still working on how to multiply these two values..)

$$
\frac{3}{4\sqrt[4]{\frac{8+x^3}{x^2}}} \cdot (1 - \frac{16}{x^3}) 
$$

How can I verify that these answers are actually the same value?

Comment: If you just want confidence, plug in a few easy numbers for $x$ and see if you get the same thing.  Or you could graph both expressions.

Comment: @B.Goddard that is a great suggestion. I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{3(x^3-16)}{4x^3\sqrt[4]{\frac{8}{x^2} + x}}= \frac{3(x^3-16)}{4x^3}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{\frac{8+x^3}{x^2}}}= \frac{3(x^3 - 16)}{4x^3} \sqrt[4]{\frac{x^2}{x^3 + 8}}$$

Also, the same way,

$$\frac{3}{4\sqrt[4]{\frac{8+x^3}{x^2}}} \cdot (1 - \frac{16}{x^3})=\frac{3}{4\sqrt[4]{\frac{8+x^3}{x^2}}} \cdot ({\frac{x^3-16}{x^3}})= \frac{3(x^3-16)}{4x^3\sqrt[4]{\frac{8}{x^2} + x}}= \frac{3(x^3-16)}{4x^3}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{\frac{8+x^3}{x^2}}}= \frac{3(x^3 - 16)}{4x^3} \sqrt[4]{\frac{x^2}{x^3 + 8}}$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\sqrt[4]{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{b}{a}}}
\end{align*}